# In what language is this page written

Tags: c#, asp.net

my question is the following

I need to change a menu in this page, but how do I recognize how this page was written.
Normally, I do stuff in php, but this is new to me.

I can see the words asp and c#, but it is not developed as a "dot net thing", is it?
..otherwise I would need visual studio, I guess?

the homepage code

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="_Default, App_Web_npdtwtc3" masterpagefile="~/Site.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.2.74.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">



<p align="left">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<font size="9">Multi Mind</font> <br /><br /> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<IMG SRC="images/contactgegevens3.png" ALT="" ALIGN=RIGHT><br />  
Tax Recruitment is de specialist op het gebied van arbeidsbemiddeling voor fiscalisten.<br />
Het richt zich
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: That's ASP.NET. So yes, you will need Visual Studio or Visual Web Developer at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a ASP.NET Web Forms page (ie. `.aspx`).

So mostly mark up, either run on the server (elements with `runat="server"`) or client (other HTML elements) but there is some JavaScript using JQuery.

For an introduction to ASP.NET Web Forms try here (this is .NET v4, but has links to the pages for earlier versions): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178125.aspx

Comment: @devcoder: Been done for me... thanks for noticing the significant typo.

Answer (score 1):

It's an ASP.NET Web Site or Application (someone help explain the difference in this context) and that particular file is an ASP.NET Web Form. There's generally no need for Visual Web Developer, you could use any text editor really - but it sure makes it easier.

Note that your example uses master pages so you're only looking at the unique content for that particular page - the menu you're after is likely the same across different pages (?) and hence specified in a master file (the name and path to it is defined on the first line). Perhaps looking at that file would make things clearer.

Comment: thank you, that helps. I also need to get accainted(don't know if the spelling is correct)with the ide to connect everything offline, etc

Answer (score 0):

This is ASP.NET with C# as the code-behind. Also a little bit of javascript in there. You will most likely need Visual Studio to edit this easily. You can get visual studio express for free from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express

Good luck with your work.

Answer (score 0):

As stuartmclark mentioned, this is an ASP.net page with C# as code behind language. To explain this,

`language="C#"` tells you that the code behind is C#. If you are now aware of code behind concept, you can think of this as server side script.

`asp:` anything starting with asp: are the ASP.net controls. This tells that this is an asp.net page.

And yes, to work on this you need either Visual Studio or Visual Web Developer. You can downlaod Visual Web Developer from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express). It's free (as in free beer) from MicroSoft.

Hope this will clarify your doubt.

Comment: thanks, everyone Would it be easy for somebody to change something with visual webdeveloper without to much knowledge about it. Mainly, giving it another menu??? Do I have everything I need with visual webdeveloper???

Comment: @Richard, well this actually depends on how the menus are programmed. If this is HTML or Java, it should be easier for you, but again that depends on person to person. Regarding prerequisites for visual web developer, if you install it directly from web, it will install everything for you (assuming that you are on a Windows XP or later machine). You may also need the database to which the application connects.